# An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild. Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

Tags: node.js, electron, zeromq, zerorpc, electron-rebuild

I am trying to use zeroRPC but I got this error:

```
electron/js2c/asar.js:140
Uncaught Error:
The module
'\\?\C:\Users\Electron\\node_modules\zerorpc\node_modules\zeromq\build\Release\zmq.node'

was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72.

This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 76.

Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

Thus, I tried to use electron-rebuild but the rebuild failed. How can I fix this? 
 I have Visual Studio Community 2017 Desktop development with C++ and Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 Desktop Visual C++ build tools.

---

[image]
[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVLJ0.jpg)

---

[image]
[Fig.2 - Dependencies:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLILK.png)

Comment: Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Explain your expected behavor and what error occours.

Comment: Try using 2015 Visual Studio build tools.